# Getting application context for getInstance function of database class (android kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, repository-pattern, android-viewmodel

I am writing an android application following the Android Architectural Components design.

This is the database class:

```
@Database(entities = [Authentication::class],version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AuthDB: RoomDatabase(){
    abstract val authenticationDao :AuthenticationAccessObject

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AuthDB? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AuthDB {
            synchronized(this){
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        AuthDB::class.java,
                        "authentication_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
                            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the Repository class:

```
class Repository2() {

private val database: AuthDB = AuthDB.getInstance(context = getContext())
private val daoA = database.authenticationDao
//Function to register a new user to system
    fun insertAuth(userData: Any){
        if (userData is Authentication){
            daoA.insertAuth(userData)
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
```

My target is that when I write the ViewModel, I want to create instance of Repository2 and call functions for example as follows:

```
var repo = Repository2()
repo.insertAuth(authenticationObject)
```

I am having problem giving context to getInstance in the Repository. The context should be such that when I instantiate the repository, it should automatically get the application context and instantiate the AuthDB database.

Until now,

1. I have tried to create Application class that extends Application and tried to get application context from there as suggested in another stackoverflow solution
2. Instantiated database with following code and failed:

   private val database: AuthDB = AuthDB.getInstance(context = getContext())
3. Instantiated database with following code and failed:

   private val database: AuthDB = AuthDB.getInstance(Application.getApplicationContext())

I have been trying for about two days now and nothing is working, I believe I am missing a major concept here. I hope someone can nudge me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Salik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this solution

**EDIT:-**

use this way to your RoomDatabase

```
@Database(
entities = [CompaniesModel::class, CompaniesHomeModel::class, UserPoint::class, Image::class, Offer::class, Rewords::class, BranchModel::class, PointsModel::class, RedeemModel::class, MainData::class, SubData::class],
version = 15)
abstract class DataBase : RoomDatabase() {


    abstract fun homeDao(): HomeDao
    abstract fun menuDao(): MenuDao
    abstract fun companiesDao(): CompaniesListDao

    abstract fun branchesDao(): BranchesDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var databaseInstance: DataBase? = null

        fun getDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context): DataBase =
            databaseInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
                databaseInstance ?: buildDatabaseInstance(mContext).also {
                    databaseInstance = it
                }
            }

        private fun buildDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(mContext, DataBase::class.java, "crm")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()

    }
}
```

and for the getContext(), use Application() class like this:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this

    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
    }
}
```

and pass it like this

```
private val database: AuthDB = AuthDB.getInstance(app.instance)
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome
can you give the answer (this answer is useful) please